# Why does master Roshi want the plane to stop before the second Tenkaichi tournament?

Tags: dragon-ball

In Dragon Ball, master Roshi and the others take a plane trip over to Papaya island for the 2nd Tenkaichi tournament (in the series). During the plane-ride, master Roshi seems to become extremely upset and wants the plane to stop. I watched this a few times, and I guess I just didn't understand this part.

Why does he want the plane to stop?

Comment: which episode or chapter is this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Episode 84: Rivals and Arrivals
(English Dub)**

> **Roshi**: *grunt* Help... *grunt*
>
> **Stewardess**: Uh, sir, are you alright?
>   Is something the matter?
>
> **R**: *grunt* I want off this plane right now!
>   *grunt*
>
> **S**: I see...
>
> **R**: Land or get me a parachute. Either way, I'm leaving!
>
> **[Bulma, Yamcha, Krillin]**: *gasp*
>
> **S**: Uh, um, sir, I'm sorry,
>   but it's impossible for anyone to leave the plane for it lands. Please
>   sit back and try to relax. Can I get you a pillow or some peanuts?
>
> **R**:
>   I don't want peanuts; I want this bird on the ground! Now go tell the
>   captain!
>
> **S**: Yes sir. GRR!
>
> **Oolong**: I'll take some peanuts!
>
> **Krillin**:
>   Oh...
>
> **R**: Grr... *grunts*
>
> **K**: *blushes* Oh...Master, please get control
>   of yourself. This is embarrassing.
>
> **Yamcha**: *blushes* (Internally) From
>   now on I'm travelling alone.
>
> **Bulma**: *blushes* ...

---

**Episode 84: Aim to be the World's Best Martial Artist!
(English Sub)**

> **Roshi**: *grunt*
>
> **Stewardess**: Ah, excuse me...Your seatbelt, sir.
>
> **R**: *grunt* Stewardess!
>
> **S**: Uh, yes?
>
> **R**: I really need to take a dump!
>
> **[Bulma, Yamcha, Krillin]**: *gasp*
>
> **S**: Ah... A dump...?
>   I'm sorry, but we'll be landing momentarily;
>   could you hold it in for just a little longer?
>
> **R**:
>   Very well...! Please land quickly!
>
> **S**: Certainly! Eugh...
>
> **R**: Grr... *grunts*
>
> **Krillin**: *gasps* *blushes* Muten Roshi-sama. Please don't embarrass us.
>
> **Yamcha**: *blushes* (Internally) Pretend you don't know him...!
>
> **Bulma**: *blushes* ...

---

As you can see in the comparison above, the potty talk was censored in the English Dub. In the end, the reason Roshi wanted to land in the English dub wasn't made clear at all. They didn't even bother coming up with an alternate explanation! If the studio was afraid to air potty jokes on the US airwaves, they should've cut the scene altogether or come up with a new reason (a tummy ache?).

With the Dub being my first exposure to this scene, and considering Roshi's pervy past with his workout videos and lewd magazines (making me assume he's a sex/masturbatory addict), I thought Roshi wanted to land because he was unbearably eager to "relieve" himself after being around the pretty stewardess for so long. The other characters' unexplained blushing only added to this theory.

This is a scene whose meaning was truly lost in translation..

Answer (score 6):

If you're talking about the manga, Master Roshi indeed wants the plane to stop, but the reason is quite obvious to the reader: he wants to poop real bad (Chapter 113). This is so clearly stated that I am not sure this is what you were asking about. Maybe it is not so clear in the anime?

[image]